# HTML Table redesign

Tags: html, wordpress, html-table

I am redesigning my website so that the right navigation categories -Occasion and Project Type - are side by side ([http://www.merrimentdesign.com][1]). However, when I implement the table, I can't seem to get them to align correctly. Here is my code:

I've taken some of your advice and div'd them up as opposed to using tables. But now, I'm wondering how to style them so that they are side by side. New with CSS so bear with me.

```
<div id="right">
<table class="categories">
<tr>
<td>
<img class="categories" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/images/sidebar.gif" alt="Let The Merriment Begin..." title="Let The Merriment Begin..." /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="categorycontent">
<br />
<div id = "occasion">
<h1>Occasion</h1>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=537'); ?>
</ul>
</div>

<div id = "ptype">
<h1>Project Type</h1>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=538'); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps a ss would help?

Comment: please add your CSS so that we can get a better picture of your task.

Comment: also, tables are not good for this type of application. Try using a list - http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/css-vertical-navigation-with-teaser/

Comment: Please don't use `table` elements for layout; it's really not-nice. Nor is it, apparently, any easier.

Comment: Why don't you recommend a better solution? That is what he's asking for..

Comment: aarrggh!! it's a WALL of code!!!

Comment: ss=screenshot, but css helps too ;p

Comment: I posted a link in my comment to recommend a `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

float:right; the div with a fixed width, float:left; the list elements within? I can't really tell what it is you are asking but from looking at your site, it seems that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with how it is displayed now? That is, what is the result you'd like to have?

If you'd go tableless, which some of the commenters suggested (and I do too), you'd solve this using divs instead. Have a look at for instance http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa102102a.htm to learn more about how to do that. Or google "tableless css" for even more.

Comment: So essentially I would have to div the two categories?

Comment: That would probably be better yes.

Comment: I've taken your advice and div'd up the two categories. How should I go about placing them side by side within the right navigation? I've re-edited my post to include my new code.

Comment: CSS is really not one of my main areas. I guess it'd have to do with display: and maybe float:? :)